# Format Highcharts chart tooltip pointFormat in formatter

Tags: highcharts

How to display series.name in tooltip formatter? Currently it displays just {series.name}.

```
 tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>{series.name}: ' +    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>';

                }
            },
```

EDIT:

```
new tooltip has been initially created in c# 
tooltip = new { pointFormat = "<span style=\"color:   {series.color}\">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.1f}</b><br/>" };
```

...and I am able to overwrite the value this.y to 2 decimal places but get stuck by displaying the series.name

Comment: Please, attach all `tooltip` options. Answer may vary according to your options (however, answer below should work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.name + ': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would have thought that too but this doesn't render anything. If I leave this.series.name out it renders just this.y with 2 decimal places. ...any other ideas?

Comment: does your series have a name? Could I take a look at your series object? Because I tried this code on mine and it works. So there is nothing wrong here.